# Product special_price only changes with reindex

Tags: magento2, product, price, rest-api, special-price

I'm trying to set a product special_price using rest api, But the special_price only changes in store front with reindex command.

PS: When i use a numeric value, like: 15, 100, etc... it changes perfectly. But when i try to set null it only changes with reindex command.

> rest/default/V1/products/

```
{"product": {
  "sku": "86300-UNICO-UN",
  "custom_attributes": [
      {  
        "attribute_code": "special_price",
        "value": null
      }
  ]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it via a POST to another API endpoint.

If any item to be deleted has an invalid `price`, `store_id`, `sku` or `date`, Magento marks the item as failed and excludes it from the delete list. Valid items are deleted as requested.

Sending a post to the endpoint:

```
<host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/products/special-price-delete
```

With this content for example:

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "price": 5,
      "store_id": 0,
      "price_from": "2017-07-15 00:00:00",
      "price_to": "2017-07-16 23:59:59",
      "sku": "86300-UNICO-UN"
    }
  ]
}
```

This might solve your issue.

**But make sure that your crons are running well, and you're not having a lot of missed cron jobs.**

I usually do it running [Magerun 2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) command below.

```
./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:history
```